# Aerospike Test Environment

Tags: go, aerospike

I'm planning on stubbing out a namespace, but what is the current state of deleting a whole namespace? Would I have to list out all the keys that exists, and manually go through and delete them? If so, what API call would that be to list all sets, and then keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [truncate-namespace](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/info/?show-removed=1#truncate-namespace) command (run from within `asadm` to issue against all nodes):

`asinfo -v 'truncate-namespace:namespace=test;'`

In the Community Edition a restart would resurrect the truncated records (unless enough new updates have overwritten those records). The Enterprise Edition would make the truncation 'durable' and prevent any record to be resurrected upon any types of restart (cold or fast).

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your test environment is fairly small, your best bet is to store data in ram and restart the service for each run.